# How to send hastag access_token posted by url to server inorder to use it further

Tags: json, yii, youtube

I will explain in detail, I am trying to authorize the youtube my webapp. For that I post as below

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  client_id=1084945748469-eg34p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  redirect_uri=http://www.abc.com/site/video&
  scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&
  response_type=token
```

And youtube respond that request by JSON object

http://www.abc.com/site/video#access_token=ya29.AH6RkxRG81F7H9vZLcA4wmzzzgJlmBSduk-oDxom5w&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

Now I want to send the access_token since this is hastag data I can't access it anyway using php on server side, I know I have to send it to server using AJAX or JSON somehow. Also I am using Yii framework if there is some Yii method I would be happy to use. If no choice I will use

Comment: Why you cant use response? I believe you use cURL to send your authorization, so you'll have json string in response. Resposne will be `$data = curl_exec($ch);`. Just use it.